# Solving a triple integral with Spherical Coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am attempting to solve this integral $\iiint \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2)}} \mathrm{dV}$ where the region $v$ is a unit sphere.

How would I go about converting the function inside the integral to the spherical system?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most straightforwardly, you can plug in in $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z=r\cos\theta$, as well as the volume element in spherical coordinates $dV=r^2\sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$. I won't actually do this for you, because I suspect this is homework, and this should be enough for you to get started. You could also skip a couple of steps by noting that $x^2+y^2=\rho^2=r^2\sin^2\theta$, or even better by drawing a diagram and seeing what length the denominator in your integral represents, and using the law of cosines (hint: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is the length of the vector connecting the origin to $(x,y,z)$.)

EDIT: The boundary is still just the unit sphere, i.e., you integrate over the region $0\le r<1$, $0\le \theta<\pi$ and $0\le \phi<2\pi$.

Comment: Hey! Thanks.

I've tried to use this method, but unfortunately I can't seem to get the boundaries correct.

Comment: Edited answer to specify boundaries. Your question asked how to convert the integrand into spherical, and so I told you how to do that. That is probably not the best way to actually proceed with the integral (I can think of an easier way). If you'd like me to suggest an easier way to compute the integral, edit the question to say that, and let me know and I'll be happy to suggest something.

Comment: My previous comment is slightly misleading, so just to clarify - the integral is definitely doable in a straightforward manner, i.e. with a standard table of integrals and without any non-trivial tricks, after converting to spherical coordinates or in fact even in Cartesian coordinates. Its just that the integral is messiest in Cartesian, then neater in spherical and then even neater in another (fairly standard) coordinate system (though of course, neatness is somewhat subjective).

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Cylindrical.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

First, do a simple transformation like $x'=x, y'=y, z'=z-2$.